# Python future gets slower after a while

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice

I am submitting jobs using python 3 `concurrent.futures`.

```
lock = threading.Lock()
def do_the_work(item):
    t1, t2 = find_delta(item[1]['file1'], item[1]['file2'])
    datapoint = (t1, t2)

    while lock.locked():
       continue

    lock.acquire()
    writer.writerow(datapoint)
    lock.release()
    print('Done writing to csv')

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=os.cpu_count()) as executor:
    futures = [executor.submit(do_the_work, item) for item in work_list.items()]
```

Initially, this code runs very fast. But after a while, i.e. after processing ~50K records it becomes dead-slow.

Here, I don't see any issues with deadlock. Futures once they can hold the lock, just writing to the file. Then why it's acting like this?

CPU load becomes very high which is strange as well. While running machine has enough free memory.

I know I can write the code again with the producer, consumer with a queue. But I don't understand what's wrong with the above code.

I am wondering is there a way to solve this problem using the `concurrent.futures`?

Comment: How does `writer.writerow` work?  Do we expect `do_the_work` to be primarily i/o bound?  If not than threading might not be helpful.

Comment: It is `csvwriter.writerow` which is writing to a shared file which is the bottleneck.